# Mark a cell in my datagrid when the program starts

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus, cell

I can easily programmatically mark a cell in my datagrid using the following code:

```
DataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid1.Items[Rowindex]);
DataGrid1.Focus();                                                          
DataGrid1.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(DataGrid1.Items[Rowindex], DataGrid1.Columns[Columnindex]);
DataGrid1.SelectedCells.Clear();                                            
DataGrid1.SelectedCells.Add(DataGrid1.CurrentCell);
```

However, this only works after I've started my program once and the datagrid has fully loaded. However, I try to do the scrolling and highlighting on the first launch. My method call looks like this:

```
public DataBaseWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
// Here i do some other Stuff.
jump_to_cell();
}
public void jump_to_cell()
{
DataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid1.Items[Rowindex]);
DataGrid1.Focus();                                                          
DataGrid1.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(DataGrid1.Items[Rowindex], DataGrid1.Columns[Columnindex]);
DataGrid1.SelectedCells.Clear();                                            
DataGrid1.SelectedCells.Add(DataGrid1.CurrentCell); 
}
```

When I select a cell programmatically the selection is highlighted. However, not when I start the program for the first time. Then unfortunately nothing happens.

EDIT: I found a solution to the problem. If I just set the method call after the .Show method, it works. =>

```
DatabaseWindow DB1 = new DatabaseWindow(); 
DB1.Owner = this; 
DB1.Show(); 
DB1.jump_to_cell();
```

Comment: You "have a feeling"? What does that mean? What happens when you run the app and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi Mario. It's not clear what you mean by "mark a cell". Do you mean selecting a cell?

Comment: Ye sorry. Selecting Cell / Highlight the selected cell

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. If I just set the method call after the .Show method, it works. Does someone know why? Kind regards

```
DatabaseWindow DB1 = new DatabaseWindow();
                        DB1.Owner = this;                                                
                        DB1.Show();                                                      
                        DB1.jump_to_cell();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the WindowLoaded or ContentRendered Events.

```
<Window ...
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">



private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
    }
```